# Deserializing an abstract class in Gson

Tags: java, json, abstract-class, gson

I have a tree object in JSON format I'm trying to deserialize with Gson.  Each node contains its child nodes as fields of object type Node.  Node is an interface, which has several concrete class implementations.  During the deserialization process, how can I communicate to Gson which concrete class to implement when deserializing the node, if I do not know a priori which type the node belongs to?  Each Node has a member field specifying the type.  Is there a way to access the field when the object is in serialized form, and somehow communicate the type to Gson?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look to [http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081826/3315914](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22081826/3315914)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I'd suggest adding a custom [JsonDeserializer](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) for `Node`s:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapter(Node.class, new NodeDeserializer())
    .create();
```

You will be able to access the `JsonElement` representing the node in the deserializer's method, convert that to a `JsonObject`, and retrieve the field that specifies the type. You can then create an instance of the correct type of `Node` based on that.

Comment: @eng-carlin It's customary to upvote and accept an answer if it works for you, so if you could do that I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The green check mark has been clicked.  I'd upvote you, but my reputation isn't high enough :(

Comment: @ColinD I have a GSON related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35732503/how-to-make-json-string-using-gson). If possible can help me out.

Comment: The link is dead. It's usually better to add a short description than a link :)

Comment: The JsonDeserializer documentation states: "New applications should prefer [TypeAdapter](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/TypeAdapter.html), whose streaming API is more efficient than this interface's tree API." Just fyi to anyone for whom efficiency matters.

Answer (score 38):

You will need to register both JSONSerializer and JSONDeserializer. Also you can implement a generic adapter for all your interfaces in the following way:

- During Serialization : Add a META-info of the actual impl class type.
- During DeSerialization : Retrieve that meta info and call the JSONDeserailize of that class

Here is the implementation that I have used for myself and works fine.

```
public class PropertyBasedInterfaceMarshal implements
        JsonSerializer<Object>, JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    private static final String CLASS_META_KEY = "CLASS_META_KEY";

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type,
            JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext)
            throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject jsonObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
        String className = jsonObj.get(CLASS_META_KEY).getAsString();
        try {
            Class<?> clz = Class.forName(className);
            return jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonElement, clz);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Object object, Type type,
            JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
        JsonElement jsonEle = jsonSerializationContext.serialize(object, object.getClass());
        jsonEle.getAsJsonObject().addProperty(CLASS_META_KEY,
                object.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return jsonEle;
    }

}
```

Then you could register this adapter for all your interfaces as follows

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(IInterfaceOne.class,
                new PropertyBasedInterfaceMarshal())
        .registerTypeAdapter(IInterfaceTwo.class,
                new PropertyBasedInterfaceMarshal()).create();
```

Comment: what do u mean by IInterfaceOne.class and IInterfaceTwo.class

Comment: Thank you for providing the most elegant/reusable solution to this problem. I use `_class` as `CLASS_META_KEY` like mongodb does.

Comment: **Please do not use `Class.forName`**. This allows an attacker to load arbitrary classes, create instances of them and set arbitrary field values. Instead maintain a mapping of type names to the corresponding `Class` (this also makes it easier to integrate with non-Java services). You can use gson-extras `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` for that, see answers on https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736654

Answer (score 3):

I want to correct the above a little

```
public class PropertyMarshallerAbstractTask implements JsonSerializer<Object>, JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    private static final String CLASS_TYPE = "CLASS_TYPE";

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonElement jsonElement, Type type, JsonDeserializationContext jsonDeserializationContext) throws JsonParseException {

        JsonObject jsonObj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
       String className = jsonObj.get(CLASS_TYPE).getAsString();

        try {
            Class<?> clz = Class.forName(className);
            return jsonDeserializationContext.deserialize(jsonElement, clz);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new JsonParseException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Object object, Type type, JsonSerializationContext jsonSerializationContext) {
    
        Gson gson = new Gson(); //without this line it will not work
        gson.toJson(object, object.getClass()); //and this one
        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(object); //it needs to replace to another method...toJsonTree
        jsonElement.getAsJsonObject().addProperty(CLASS_TYPE, object.getClass().getCanonicalName());
        return jsonElement;
    }
}
```

And then I use it:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(AbstractTask.class, new PropertyMarshallerOfAbstractTask())
                .create();
```

And then I can parse List (where I keep some non-abstract classes, which inherited from Abstract Task) to Json;

And it works in the opposite direction

```
List<AbstractTask> abstractTasks = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<AbstractTask>>(){}.getType());
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell this doesn't work for non-collection types, or more specifically, situations where the concrete type is used to serialize, and the interface type is used to deserialize.  That is, if you have a simple class implementing an interface and you serialize the concrete class, then specify the interface to deserialize, you'll end up in an unrecoverable situation.

In the above example the type adapter is registered against the interface, but when you serialize using the concrete class it will not be used, meaning the CLASS_META_KEY data will never be set.

If you specify the adapter as a hierarchical adapter (thereby telling gson to use it for all types in the hierarchy), you'll end up in an infinite loop as the serializer will just keep calling itself.

Anyone know how to serialize from a concrete implementation of an interface, then deserialize using only the interface and an InstanceCreator?

By default it seems that gson will create the concrete instance, but does not set it's fields.

Issue is logged here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=411&q=interface

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `TypeToken` class from Google Gson. 
You will need of course has a generic class T to make it works

```java
Type fooType = new TypeToken<Foo<Bar>>() {}.getType();
```

gson.toJson(foo, fooType);

```
gson.fromJson(json, fooType);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and I got `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Abstract class can't be  instantiated!`

Comment: ConnectRecord is abstract, you cannot use it for deserialize the Json

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to use the `TypeAdapter` solutions above, and had almost given up on serializing. In the end I found a solution in an intermediary step between the class object and Gson. I serialized the object itself into a byte array, and then Gson serialized the byte array + deserializing back in similar fashion.

```java
public class GenericSerializer {
  public static byte[] serializeForClass(final Object obj) {
    try {
      final var byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      final var objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
      objectOutputStream.writeObject(obj);
      objectOutputStream.flush();
      objectOutputStream.close();
      return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      LOG.warn("Unable to serialize for class '%s'".formatted(obj.getClass().getName()), e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static <T> T deserializeForClass(final byte[] serializedObj, final Class<T> cls) {
    if (serializedObj == null) {
      return null;
    }
    try {
      final var inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedObj);
      final var objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
      return cls.cast(objectInputStream.readObject());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException | NullPointerException e) {
      LOG.warn("Unable to deserialize for class '%s'".formatted(cls), e);
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Used like this

```java
final var yourObject = new YourClass();
final var serialized = GenericSerializer.serializeForClass(yourObject);
final var gson = new Gson();
final var gsonSerialized = gson.toJson(serialized);
final var gsonDeserialized = gson.fromJson(gsonSerialized, byte[].class)
final var deserialized =  GenericSerializer.deserializeForClass(gsonDeserialized, YourClass.class);
assert(yourObject == deserialized);
```

I'm hoping this might help someone else the way it helped me.