# Wrap certain values when serializing JSON with Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

How can I wrap certain values when serializing an object model to JSON with GSON? Example model:

```
class Order {
  Customer cust;
}

class Customer {
  String name;
  int age;
}
```

Serializing a Customer would normally yield something like:

```
{cust:{name:joe, age:21}}
```

What I would like to do is wrap the Order and Customer values in an additional element with the class name. So the expected JSON would be:

```
{Order:{cust:Customer:{name:joe, age:21}}}
```

The actual classes that I'll be serializing could be anything, so I can't hardcode specific properties in a serializer. But I will want to wrap certain properties with their class name.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you *absolutely* need the wrapping part, or can you achieve a similar functionality by adding a "clazz" field to your model objects?

Comment: I don't own the objects I'll be serializing and deserializing, so no I can't add anything to them.

Comment: Sure, but at serialization time you can add a `clazz` field holding the fully qualified class name, so when deserializing you can read that `clazz` and get back the Java type with `Class.forName`. You only need to do this for the root element, since then you can use the standard Gson routines. I looked deeply into the Gson API and sources, and it seems that the kind of *decoration* you are looking for is impossible to do (at least I didn't find an easy way without modifying the sources). There are other libraries, of course, and you could try to specify why the type of the response is unknown

Comment: It's easy to decorate an element: new JsonObject().add(rootElementName, gson.toJsonTree(object, targetType))...What I can't sort out is how to do this for arbitrary elements within a document. In other words, it's easy to do for the root element, but how would I do this for some element 5 levels deep?

Comment: Sure, I meant that the harder part is doing for arbitrairly deep nesting levels :-) still I can't figure out why you need this. Once you have the root type, Gson can deserialize and build the object via reflection

Comment: Gson can only deserialize objects using reflection if you tell it what the type is. I can unwrap the top level type and see that it's an Order, and tell Gson to deserialize it as an order, but if there's a customer several levels deep, Gson won't know how to deserialize that unless there's a TypeAdapter or Deserializer registered for that specific type. That's the problem.

Comment: maybe I don't uderstand your point. See [this paste](http://pastebin.com/pGfybjAp) and tell me if your problem is a different one

Comment: Try making Customer an interface with different implementations. Gson won't know which implementation to deserialize with.

Comment: This is a different question :) see [Deserializing in Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629596/deserializing-an-abstract-class-in-gson) or [Polymorphism with Gson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800433/polymorphism-with-gson) and finally [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=231) Basically you have to write serializers and deserializers for fields defined with an abstract type

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid json string though:

```
{Order:{cust:Customer:{name:joe, age:21}}}
```

In you application, you have to model/implement your domain class properly before it can be used for serializing/deserializing json string, in another word, the domain class should be known before calling toJson/fromJson method. However the actual domain class type can be determined dynamically at runtime, By using Java Generic Type.

Check out the section [Serializing and Deserializing Generic Types](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Gener) from Gson User Guide:

```
public class Foo<T> {
  public T value;
}
```

To serialize it:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type fooType = new TypeToken<Foo<Bar>>() {}.getType();
gson.toJson(foo, fooType);
```

To deserialize it:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type fooType = new TypeToken<Foo<Bar>>() {}.getType();
gson.fromJson(json, fooType);
```

Comment: The point of this is that I *don't* know what class I'm deserializing to - that's why I want to wrap certain elements in the class name.

Comment: If the class type is unknown, it is unnecessary to deserialize this part of json string to a concrete java object. Probably you can alter you json string and organize multiple json fileds/infos as a raw string, when serialize/deserialize with gson, these multiple json fields/infos are treated as regular java string type.