# There is a way to know which type json is represent?

Tags: java, json, gson

let's say i have two objects: Person and ReqSingUp, and ReqSingUp contains Person.

Now if i try:

```
Person p=new Person("dan","lala");
ReqSingUp reqSingUp=new ReqSingUp(p);
String s = gson.toJson(reqSingUp,ReqSingUp.class);
Object o = gson.fromJson(s, Object.class);

if (o instanceof ReqSingUp) {
    System.out.println("it's ReqSingUp");
}
if (o instanceof Person ) {
    System.out.println("it's person");
}
```

it does not satisfy any condition (not `instanceof ReqSingUp` and not `instanceof Person`  ).

Is there a way to know which type it is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. I don't think there is a way. May be one work around is use one of the json tag to represent type of object.

Comment: Have you looked at the guide? This may help: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and-Deserializing-Collection-with-Objects-of-Arbitrary-Types

Comment: Isn't this a variation of this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629596/deserializing-an-abstract-class-in-gson

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to directly know it.

This because the information contained in a JSon file doesn't contain directly any type information about the object that is serialized in there. That's why you usually provide the class when reading a JSon file, as in

```
fromJSon(myObject, MyClass.class)
```

This indeed creates problem even when reading collection of arbitrary types or genericized objects.