# How to handle deserializing with polymorphism?

Tags: java, gson

I have a class like:

```
public class Barn {
    String type;
    Animal animal;
}

public class Horse extends Animal {
}

public class Cow extends Animal {
}
```

and I want to serialize a list of them:

```
List<Barn> barns = new ArrayList<Barn>();

Barn barn1 = new Barn();
barn1.setType("horse");
barn1.setAnimal(new Horse());
barns.add(barn1);

Barn barn2 = new Barn();
barn2.setType("cow");
barn2.setAnimal(new Cow());
barns.add(barn2);

...

Group<Barn> barns = gson.fromJson(serialized);
```

When I serialize, type information will be lost for the Animal attribute. Is there a way I could install a parser listener somehow so that I could provide the right class to deserialize as when each element in the list is encountered? That was the idea behind manually supplying a string describing the class type.

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the Gson project code base is [the RuntimeTypeAdapter](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java), which reportedly works well for polymorphic serialization and deserialization.  I don't think I've yet tried to use it.  See http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=231 for more info.  Note, it hasn't yet been included in any Gson releases.

If use of it doesn't fit your needs, then custom deserialization processing is necessary.  Following is one such approach, assuming you want to use the JSON structure demonstrated.  (I'd take a somewhat different approach, if the JSON structure could be different.)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParseException;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class App
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Barn[] barns = {new Barn(), new Barn()};
    barns[0].type = "horse";
    barns[0].animal = new Horse();
    barns[1].type = "cow";
    barns[1].animal = new Cow();

    String json = new Gson().toJson(barns);
    // [{"type":"horse","animal":{}},{"type":"cow","animal":{}}]

    BarnDeserializer deserializer = new BarnDeserializer("type");
    deserializer.registerBarnType("horse", Horse.class);
    deserializer.registerBarnType("cow", Cow.class);
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Barn.class, deserializer).create();

    List<Barn> barns2= gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Barn>>(){}.getType());
    for (Barn barn : barns2)
    {
      System.out.println(barn.animal.getClass());
    }
  }
}

class BarnDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Barn>
{
  String barnTypeElementName;
  Gson gson;
  Map<String, Class<? extends Animal>> barnTypeRegistry;

  BarnDeserializer(String barnTypeElementName)
  {
    this.barnTypeElementName = barnTypeElementName;
    gson = new Gson();
    barnTypeRegistry = new HashMap<>(); // Java 7 required for this syntax.
  }

  void registerBarnType(String barnTypeName, Class<? extends Animal> animalType)
  {
    barnTypeRegistry.put(barnTypeName, animalType);
  }

  @Override
  public Barn deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) 
      throws JsonParseException
  {
    JsonObject barnObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    JsonElement animalTypeElement = barnObject.get(barnTypeElementName);
    Barn barn = new Barn();
    barn.type = animalTypeElement.getAsString(); 
    Class<? extends Animal> animalType = barnTypeRegistry.get(barn.type);
    barn.animal = gson.fromJson(barnObject.get("animal"), animalType);
    return barn;
  }
}

class Barn {String type; Animal animal;}
class Animal {}
class Horse extends Animal {}
class Cow extends Animal {}
```

Comment: Could this code work if the subtypes (horse, cow) are in different Maven projects than Barn? 

I have a circular dependency with Jackson deserialization and trying to find a solution

Answer (score 13):

You could use [Gson Fire](https://github.com/julman99/gson-fire) for this. The code would look something like this:

```java
GsonFireBuilder builder = new GsonFireBuilder()
    .registerTypeSelector(Barn.class, new TypeSelector<Barn>() {
        @Override
        public Class<? extends Barn> getClassForElement(JsonElement readElement) {
            String type = readElement.getAsJsonObject().get("type").getAsString();
            if(type.equals("horse")){
                return Horse.class; 
            } else if(type.equals("cow")) {
                return Cow.class;
            } else {
                return null; //returning null will trigger Gson's default behavior
            }
        }
    });
Gson gson = builder.createGson();
```

Answer (score 13):

You don't need to write your own Adapter.

Finally gson has its own [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) to handle java polymorphism but unfortunately it's not part of the gson core library (in order to use it you must copy and paste the class into your project).

Suppose that you have this `Animal.class`:

```
public class Animal {
    protected String name;
    protected String type;

    public Animal(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

And `Horse.class`:

```
public class Horse extends Animal {
    public Horse(String name) {
        super(name, "horse");
    }
}
```

You can initialize the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` using the code below:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Animal> runtimeTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
.of(Animal.class, "type")
.registerSubtype(Horse.class, "horse")
.registerSubtype(Cow.class, "cow");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(runtimeTypeAdapterFactory)
    .create();
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134470/how-does-polymorphism-work-with-gson-retrofit/47189060#47189060) you can find a full working example.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not appear to work unless both the classes and labels are unique. For instance, one could not have `.registerSubtype(A.class "alfa")` and `.registerSubtype(A.class "alpha")` - this will result in an `IllegalArgumentException` at runtime.

Comment: Also of note, Google neither maintains nor publishes an official package for their [`gson-extras`](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1104#issuecomment-543759867) library and, while there is a third-party distribution, there is no guarantee made of support or compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interested in the feature and I've added a feature request to GSon

https://github.com/google/gson/issues/869