# GSON: Deserialize inner Object based on String in containing object

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to create a custom deserializer in Gson for an object that is really just a wrapper for a bunch of disparate types with a type identifier.

Here's a simplified overview of my problem domain:

I have users sending messages to each other that can contain a variety of unrelated domain objects, and I want to deserialize it to something like:

```
public class Message {
    public String messageType;
    public Object messageData;
}
```

The messageData object is constructed via JavaScript the programmers decided to just jam every object type into one field "messageData". messageData can be any number of domain objects like: User, Video, Website, Picture, which do not share a base class or interface.

So the (simplified) json object could look like:

```
{ "messageType": "video", "messageData": { "videoId": 1, "videoTitle": "my vid" } }
```

or

```
{ "messageType": "picture", "messageData": { "pictureId": 1, "pictureUrl": "http://www.example.com/cat.jpg" } }
```

The goal would be to take the messageType and use that to choose a proper class to deserialize it into.

I have come up with something like this:

```
public class MessageJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Message> {

    @Override
    public Message deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
        throws JsonParseException {


        JsonObject obj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        Message message = new Message();
        message.messageType = obj.get("messageType").getAsString();
        message.messageData = MessageDataMapper.map(message.messageType, obj.get("messageData")); // maps and casts to the correct Video/Picture,Website etc..
        return message;
    }
}
```

This seems to work ok, but let's say that Message has a LOT of other fields that could be automatically serialized, then I'd have to manually parse the JsonObject and extract those fields.

Is there a way that I can use a hybrid approach and have Gson automatically serialize the non-Object fields, but use a custom serializer for that messageData field that ALSO takes into account the messageType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, no. At least not that I was ever able to determine. There is no way to have it do something like "custom deserialize field X, but super.deserialize() for the rest of it". God knows I tried. If it's any consolation, that seems to be true with every Json deserializer I've looked at.

Comment: Yes, that is sad :( Thanks for sharing your experience!

Answer (score 2):

It might be a bit late, but this answer regarding the RuntimeTypeAdapter might help you in solving this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15737704/433421

The RuntimeTypeAdapter enables you to evaluate a self-configured type-attribute in the JSON, in your case "messageType", and register its values with provided POJO-classes.

Look at the link provided in this answer to see an usage-example in the javadoc.

GSon would handle serialization and deserialization of those POJO-classes itself, as I understand it.

If those fields in messageData contain arbitrary objects, you would have to register custom JsonDeserializer-instances as you did with MessageJsonDeserializer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One addition: you might have to modify the RuntimeTypeAdapter to look for the type-attribute one level up the given JSON-hierarchy, since it expects it to be in the messageData-structure.


Also, you might have to define an abstract superclass for all messageData-structures similar to the Shape.class in the javadoc-example.