# Nested JSON array with mixed objects using GSON and Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I am trying to determine how I can parse a JSON array which is nested. Additionally, the array items are of two different types (category and item). The category states that there are children and each child can be a category or an item. I found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736654/how-to-handle-deserializing-with-polymorphism), which might touch on what I am trying to do, if anyone could confirm.

`{
    "content": {
        "elements":[
        {
            "type": "category",
            "id": "1",
            "title": "category 1",
            "description": "category description 1",
            "image": 
            {
                "src": null,
                "thumb": null
            },
            "elements":[
            {
                "type": "category",
                "id": "1.1",
                "title": "category 1.1",
                "description": "category description 1.1",
                "image": 
                {
                    "src": null,
                    "thumb": null
                },
                "elements":[
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "1.1.1",
                    "title": "item 1.1.1",
                    "description": "item description 1.1.1",
                    "images":[],
                    "options":[],
                    "price":0.00,
                    "vat": 0
                }, {
                    "type": "category",
                    "id": "1.1.2",
                    "title": "category 1.1.2",
                    "description": "category description 1.1.2",
                    "image": 
                    {
                        "src": null,
                        "thumb": null
                    },
                    "elements":[
                    {
                        "type": "item",
                        "id": "1.1.2.1",
                        "title": "item 1.1.2.1",
                        "description": "item description 1.1.2.1",
                        "images":[],
                        "options":[],
                        "price":0.00,
                        "vat": 0
                    }]
                }]
            },{
                "type": "category",
                "id": "1.2",
                "title": "category 1.2",
                "description": "category description 1.2",
                "image": 
                {
                    "src": null,
                    "thumb": null
                },
                "elements": [
                {
                    "type": "item",
                    "id": "1.2.1",
                    "title": "item 1.2.1",
                    "description": "item description 1.2.1",
                    "images":[],
                    "options":[],
                    "price":0.00,
                    "vat": 0
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "type": "item",
            "id": 2,
            "title": "item 2",
            "description": "item description 2",
            "images":[],
            "options":[],
            "price":0.00,
            "vat": 0
        }]
    }
}`

To handle API calls and models, I make use of GSON.

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
              .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .create();`

I also use Retrofit

`retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("my url")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();`

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html