# Gson: Modeling a Class for JSON with variable Intern Object

Tags: java, android, json, model, gson

Goog Day to all: This is my first question and i may have failed to find a similar question, and so im posting this one.
I am making an app in android for Guild Wars 2 and I'm new, this is my first project for full implementng an app having all considerations for good practices.
As for my problem I am now, modeling the clases for JSON strings responses from GW2 API.
Lets Start with "item" API JSON:
WIKI: https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/API:2/items
EXAMPLE: https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/items/28445

I am modeling the class for GSON deserialization on A CLASS Diagram (not coded yet) and i'm having issues with the "details" object inside the "item" JSON. The "details" object is variable and may or may not have subobjects.

So the issues Are:

1. The "details" Subobject changes depending on the id requested. 
   Q1.1: Should i create a BIG detail Class with all possibilities added and use Gson to leave empty those properties who won't match? or create one class for each different subobjects (in API subobject meaning Armor, Weapon, Trinket, etc).
   Q1.2: If I pick the later option how does GSON now what subObject/class to pick?.
2. If the Subobject(2nd level) Has inner Object(3rd level) these smaller objects are only 2 kinds.
   Q2.1:should i make subclasses inside each subObject (second level) that has these objects(third level) inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1.1: the former is often a "more comfortable option" (although not as clean as the latter) as long as the various data types are simple enough. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case. So I would personally go with the latter.

Q1.2: you would have to implement your own deserializer class. A TL;DR version on how to do this can be found e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588020/gson-serialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15736654/how-to-handle-deserializing-with-polymorphism). In your deserializer you would check for attribute "type" and check whether it's "LongBow", "Armor" or whatever, and return a respective class instance.

If you're interested in more detail, you can try [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-customizing-de-serialization-and-adding-instance-creators-via-jsonadapter) or you can just google something along the lines of "JsonSerializer" or "gson polymorphic array" etc.

Q2.1: If I understand corretly, **Infix upgrade subobject** and **Infusion slots subobject** are not dependent on the particular type of item (or particular subclass for our matters), so it is not necessary to make them as inner classes or anything. I'd make classes `InfixUpgrade` and `InfusionSlot` and add those as class members where they're relevant.

Example:

```
public class LongBow {

    @SerializedName("infix_upgrade")
    private InfixUpgrade infixUpgrade;

    @SerializedName("infusion_slots")
    private ArrayList<InfusionSlot> infusionSlots;
}
```

I hope this helped a bit. Feel free to ask additional questions.

Comment: Yes. First THANK YOU. In clarificaton to Q2.  Infix upgrade subobject and Infusion slots subobject will only exist inside Armor, Weapon, Trinket and Back "details" Object. I should just put them inside those and done?
For Q1: the "details" object has type attribute, but: if it is type sword/hammer would be Weapon object is it possible to make multiple types to refer one class in GSon deserialization?

Comment: Q2: yes pretty much. Unless there is some specific difference between those subobjects for specific item types, there is no need for any more coding.
Q1: yes, you can just do something like if (type.equals("sword") || type.equals("hammer")). And return a Weapon object based on this check.

Comment: Excellent GOT IT, and also i saw that the "details" type object comes in the 1st level "type" variable of the JSON string as "weapon" so from that Type i can already know which "detail" object to pick!

Comment: Indeed, I didn't even realise this but you are right! Glad I could help, have fun developing your app!