# How does Polymorphism work with Gson (Retrofit)

Tags: java, android, json, gson, retrofit

Here is my **`Retrofit`** instance:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
ApiManager provideApiManager() {
    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory rxAdapter = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create();

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addNetworkInterceptor(new StethoInterceptor())
            .build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    GsonConverterFactory converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConstants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxAdapter)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(ApiManager.class);
}
```

Model:

```
class AbstractMessage {
    String id;
}

class TextMessage extends AbstractMessage {
    String textMessage;
}

class ImageMessage extends AbstractMessage {
    String url;
    String text;
}
```

Request:

```
@GET("direct/messages")
Observable<List<AbstractMessage>> getMessages(@Header("Authorization") String authHeader, @Body RequestObject request);
```

Executing request:

```
apiManager.getMessages(authHeader, requestObject)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Consumer<List<AbstractMessage>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List<AbstractMessage> messages) throws Exception {
            ...
        }
    });
```

When I execute a request I receive a collection of `AbstractMessage` objects. The `JSON` can contain both text and image messages. In my case `JSON` converter creates `AbstractMessage` and maps only the `id` field. How can I make converter to create `TextMessage` and `ImageMessage` objects map all matching fields and then cast it to `AbstractMessage`. Or there may be some other solution.

Comment: I don't know Gson, but if you use JacksonConverterFactory instead, you can use `@JsonTypeInfo` to create, based on a discriminator field, one type or another one. This is a good tutorial: http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance

Answer (score 41):

You must create a [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) for the objects AbstractMessage, TextMessage and ImageMessage  and then you must set it into the gson instance.

Suppose that you have those objects:

```
public class Animal {
    protected String name;
    protected String type;

    public Animal(String name, String type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    private boolean playsCatch;

    public Dog(String name, boolean playsCatch) {
        super(name, "dog");
        this.playsCatch = playsCatch;
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    private boolean chasesLaser;

    public Cat(String name, boolean chasesLaser) {
        super(name, "cat");
        this.chasesLaser = chasesLaser;
    }
}
```

This below is the *RuntimeTypeAdapter* that you need in order to deserialize (and serialize) correctly those objects:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Animal> runtimeTypeAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
    .of(Animal.class, "type")
    .registerSubtype(Dog.class, "dog")
    .registerSubtype(Cat.class, "cat");

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .registerTypeAdapterFactory(runtimeTypeAdapterFactory)
    .create();
```

The class [RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java) is not shipped with the Gson package, so you have to download it manually.

You can read more about the runtime adapter [here](https://jansipke.nl/serialize-and-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson/) and [here](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson)

Please note that the title of your question should be "Polymorphism with Gson"

I hope it helps.