# Parse a list of generic types using retrofit

Tags: parsing, generics, retrofit2

We using retrofit, OkHttp, and Gson for connecting to API in my android app.

We have an API with the following response:

```
{
  inputs: [
     {
        type: "A",
        content:{
        ....
        },
        type: "B",
        content:{
        ....
        },
        type: "C",
        content:{
        ....
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

These inputs items are generic and their type is one of the static types I have in project. Already I have 5 different types of content (A, B, C, D, E).

This is my data class for the above API model

```
data class inputs<T>(){
    @SerializedName("type")
    val type: String,
    @SeializedName("content")
    val content: T
}
```

How can I parse this API to this generic input data class?

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134470/how-does-polymorphism-work-with-gson-retrofit/47189060#47189060

Comment: Thanks, I think that should work. I will try that.