# Map Retrofit RxJava Result into sealed class Success and failure

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, sealed-class

I am using retrofit with RXJava to call my APIs, i am trying to map my call result into sealed class success and failure parts,

I did the mapping part but I am always getting this error **java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to invoke private Result() with no args**

Here is my code:

**Retrofit interface**

```
@POST("$/Test")
fun UpdateProfile(@Body testBody: TestBody): Single<Result<TestResult>>
```

**Result Sealed Class**

```
sealed class Result<T> {
data class Success<T>(val value: T) : Result<T>()
data class Failure<T>(val throwable: Throwable) : Result<T>()}
```

**Call and Mapping**

```
   webServices.UpdateProfile(testBody)
        .onErrorReturn {
            Failure(it)
        }
        .map {
            when (it) {
                is  Result.Failure ->  Failure(it.throwable)
                is  Success -> Success(it.value)
            }
        }.subscribe()
```

anyone can help with that? why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your retrofit interface return type: `Single<Result<TestResult>>`. Retrofit has no way of knowing that your `Result` is a polymorphic type, it'll just try to instantiate whichever class you specify. In this case `Result` can't be instantiated directly because it is sealed.

You need to either use a non-polymorphic return type, or [configure retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134470/how-does-polymorphism-work-with-gson-retrofit/47189060) accordingly.