# How to have multiple types for a variable in a data class in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I want to have a data class which does this:

```
data class VariantModal (
     val variantId: String,
     val variantName: String,
     val variantUnit: List<String> || variantUnitOptions
     val productId: String,
     val variantQuantity: Int
)
```

The variantUnit can either be a list of strings or a enum value,

```
enum class variantUnitOptions {
     KG,
     BUNDLE,
     BOX,
     PIECE
}
```

Since we cannot use OR like ||, I tried to use sealed class to have list of strings or enum in this way,

```
sealed class VariantUnit<T>(val value: T) {
     class ListOfUnits(value: List<String>) : VariantUnit< List<String>>(value)
     class SelectedUnit(value: variantUnitOptions) : VariantUnit<variantUnitOptions (value)
}
data class VariantModal (
    val variantId: String,
    val variantName: String,
    val variantUnit: VariantUnit<>,  //error here
    val productId: String,
    val variantQuantity: Int
    )
```

But in this way, I am getting error as Type expected, I cannot give the type right now because it can either be `List<String>` or `variantUnitOptions`. How to achieve the expected behaviour? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are nice answers given to the question, but I would like to add that usually when this kind of situation comes up, the first thing that needs to be considered is *the class design itself*. Maybe the functionality should not be part of a single class definition, or the information should be stored outside of the class. Not saying that this is the case here, but if a class tries to be two things then maybe there should be two (related) classes.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-onstrike could you suggest a resource that explains a similar situation or come up with an example? I saw such implementation all around but have a feeling, as you explain, for some of them, however, I couldn't figure out what is the alternative solution or proper approach.

Comment: Wish I could, I'd need to know more about the context, and that would make it a study, aka *work* :) Almost always it means going back to the actual objects that are *represented* by the class model. When you have an object such as `ArrivingTrain` and `LeavingTrain` (actual real live example) then there something has gone horribly wrong (there is just a `Train`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to put generic and value to `VarianUnit`. Do it like that:

```
sealed class VariantUnit {
    class ListOfUnits(val value: List<String>) : VariantUnit()
    class SelectedUnit(val value: variantUnitOptions) : VariantUnit()
}
```

then you can use sealed class as a value:

```
data class VariantModal (
    // other values
    val variantUnit: VariantUnit,
)
```

and handle it as usual sealed class:

```
fun doSomethingWithVariantUnit(variantUnit: VariantUnit) {
    when (variantUnit) {
        is VariantUnit.ListOfUnits -> {
            val unitsList: List<String> = variantUnit.value
            // unitsList is a list, take its size for example
            unitsList.size
        }
        is VariantUnit.SelectedUnit -> {
            val unitOption: variantUnitOptions = variantUnit.value
            // unitOption is an enum, take its name for example
            unitOption.name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to variantUnit in a other data class just like other values such as variant name, quantity and others

Comment: You can. I've updated the answer

Comment: Should I consider this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47134470/how-does-polymorphism-work-with-gson-retrofit/47189060) If I want to use the sealed class to convert a JSON response to a child of VariantUnit, or there is an alternative solution?

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhahani Probably, yes. Provided post answers how to use GSON in order to parse json to a child class. It doesn't matter would it be sealed class or not.

Answer (score 0):

**NOT TESTED:**

You can use [`Any`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) class type for variantUnit property. And check type by ['is'](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-any/) operator.

Example:

```
data class VariantModal(
    val variantId: String,
    val variantName: String,
    val variantUnit: Any,
    val productId: String,
    val variantQuantity: Int
)
```

Usage:

```
val objVariantModal = VariantModal("","","","",0)
val variantUnit = objVariantModal.variantUnit
if(variantUnit is String) {
    println("This is string type")
} else if (variantUnit is variantUnitOptions) {
    println("This is ENUM type")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do it by updating `VariantModel` as below:

```
data class VariantModal<T>(
  val variantId: String,
  val variantName: String,
  val variantUnit:VariantUnit<T>,
  val productId: String,
  val variantQuantity: Int,
)
```

Then you can use it as follow:

```
fun howToUse(){
    val vmList = VariantModal(
        variantId = "",
        variantName = "",
        productId = "",
        variantQuantity = 0,
        variantUnit = VariantUnit.ListOfUnits(listOf())
    )

    val vmUnitOptions = VariantModal(
        variantId = "",
        variantName = "",
        productId = "",
        variantQuantity = 0,
        variantUnit = VariantUnit.SelectedUnit(VariantUnitOptions.BOX)
    )

    val variantUnits = listOf(
        vmList.variantUnit,
        vmUnitOptions.variantUnit,
    )

    variantUnits.forEach {variantUnit->
        when (variantUnit) {
            is VariantUnit.ListOfUnits -> {}
            is VariantUnit.SelectedUnit -> {}
        }
   }
}
```

It is worth to mention @gdomo answer is the proper way to do it, IMO.

Comment: But how to use this VariatUnit as a type in any other data class, for eg: `data class Product ( val productVariants: List<VariantModal<>> ` here what argument to pass

Comment: How about this:
data class Product<T>(
    val productVariants: List<VariantModal<T>>
)