# Loading data from file causes Fatal signal 11

Tags: java, android, file, crash, gson

Saving the data works no problem. But when loading the data I get this error message

```
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa3907e44 in tid 2407 (myapplication)
```

This method saves the data using googles GSON library. The class is part of an adapter and is called every time the user presses a button in a dialog.

```
 public int saveListToFile(UserData data, Context context) {

            itemsData.add(data); 
            notifyItemInserted(itemsData.size()-1);

        String filename = "colors";
        File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), filename);
        try {
            BufferedWriter buffWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<List<UserData>>() {}.getType();
            String json = gson.toJson(itemsData, type);
            buffWriter.append(json);
            buffWriter.newLine();
            buffWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

This method loads the data using googles GSON library. This method also causes the app to crash giving the error see above

```
    public int readCurrentList() {
            String filename = "colors";
            File file = new File(getFilesDir(), filename);

                try {
                    BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String line;
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<UserData>>() {}.getType();
                    while ((line = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        itemsData.addAll((java.util.Collection<? extends UserData>) gson.fromJson(line, type));
                    }
                    buffReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return -1;
            }

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Can you check memmory consumption by your application attach a debugger or visualvm or JMC

Comment: can you post json String which you are saving ?

Comment: @ Pankaj Nimgade I'm saving Bitmap (android.graphics.Bitmap) objects. Might this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you. It took a couple minutes before it dawned on me: I was asking Gson to convert the JSON into a list of *abstract objects*. As you can't instantiate abstract classes that of course won't work, though it was a bit surprising to see the SIGSEGV instead of a better exception.

Is `UserData` an abstract class? In that case you either have to change to using another class or maybe the solution described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/9106351/467650 .