# GSON serialize a list of polymorphic Composite classes

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a set of classes with following structure

```
public abstract class Rule { .... }
public class RuleType1 extends Rule { ... }
public class RuleType2 extends Rule { ... }
public class RuleType3 extends Rule { ... }
public class RuleType4 extends Rule { ... }

public class RuleSet extends Rule {
     ... 
     private final Collection<Rule> rules;
}
```

I want to parse following json, which contains multiple **nested** `Rule` child classes. Since `RuleSet` contains `Collection` of `Rule`, it can have multiple `RuleSet` as well.

I have checked these answers already. I don't want to implement custom (de)serializer because that will make child classes less flexible. (Whoever will change classes will need to change serializer classes as well)

[Deserializing an abstract class in Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629596/deserializing-an-abstract-class-in-gson)

[Gson serialize a list of polymorphic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588020/gson-serialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects)

Here is the same json, I want to serialize/deserialize.

```
{
    "ruleType": "ruleSet",
    "rules": [
        {
            "ruleType": "ruleSet",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "ruleType": "RuleType1"
                },
                {
                    "ruleType": "ruleSet",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "ruleType": "RuleType2"
                        },
                        {
                            "ruleType": "RuleType3"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "ruleType": "ruleSet",
            "rules": [
                {
                    "ruleType": "RuleType1"
                },
                {
                    "ruleType": "ruleSet",
                    "rules": [
                        {
                            "ruleType": "RuleType3"
                        },
                        {
                            "ruleType": "RuleType4"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

### Edit after comments:

[image]
This is my class structure where `RuleSet` has `Collection<IRule> rules`

And this is my class

```java
public class SampleClass {
    public IRule parameters;
    public double defaultConfidence;
    public String ruleType;
}
```

```java
    static RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<IRule> adaptor = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(IRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(RuleSet.class)
            .registerSubtype(Rule.class);

    static RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Rule> ruleAdaptor = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.of(Rule.class)
            .registerSubtype(DocumentTypesRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(DataAttributesRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(DictionariesRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(FileFormatsRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(FileLengthRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(FileNamePatternsRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(FixedRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(ImageTypesRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(KeywordsRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(RegexesRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(SimilaritiesRule.class)
            .registerSubtype(TopicsRule.class);

    private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(adaptor)
            .registerTypeAdapterFactory(ruleAdaptor)
            .create();
```

and facing following error while calling `GSON.fromJson(response, SampleClass.class)`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface <classPath>.IRule. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.
```

Comment: Please have a look at the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/15736654; gson-extras' `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` seems to fit for your use case. Unfortunately it is not published on Maven Central though.

Comment: As I have already mentioned I have already tried `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` and it is not working for me.

Comment: You only mentioned that you did not want to implement a custom (de)serializer; you did not mention that you already tried the `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` approach. Please include the code you have so far and describe why it is not working, e.g. throwing an exception, producing wrong results (if so which), ...